# Can we get list of jobs which are present in Job Scheduling in postgresql server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to get the list of Jobs which are working in my server on database, which displays the name, job timings, etc. using a query. Is it possible in Postresql PgAdmin.

Comment: There is no job scheduler built into postgres.  What job scheduler extension are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't be using Postgres 9.1 any more to begin with